# Cómo puedo introducir por teclado el nombre del fichero a guardar C#?

Tags: c#, io

Estoy haciendo un programa que guarde los datos de 5 alumnos en un fichero de texto, y mi pregunta es: cómo puedo hacer para que el nombre del archivo lo introduzca el usuario por teclado? Este es mi código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;


public struct alumne
{
    public string nom, cognom1, cognom2, població, adreça, dni;
    public int edat;
}

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            alumne[] alumnes = new alumne [5];

            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("/Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/ConsoleApp10/ConsoleApp10/bin/Debug/exercici1.txt"))
                {
                    string line;

                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error general");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`Console.ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Vale, pero cuando? Antes de entrar al try? Hay alguna forma de hacerlo justo cuando acabe?

Comment: En principio es irrelevante antes o despues del `try`, ya que `Console.Readline` es muy raro que lance una excepcion (aunque es posible). A que te refieres con _justo cuando acabe_?

Comment: Me refiero a que el nombre del fichero debería asignarse antes de entrar al using (streamreader....) , ya que de otra forma, el programa no dispondría de un nombre para el fichero, no?

Comment: Claro, por supuesto. Crea una variable `string path=Console.ReadLine();` y despues la usas en el constructor del streamreader `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);` Ten en cuenta que deberás controlar que el path que se introduzca sea valido

Comment: En tu pregunta hablas de obtener la dirección del archivo para guardar en esa dirección, aunque en tu código la usas para leer información del archivo de texto. Guardarás información en el archivo o lo leerás para imprimir su contenido?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que el usuario pueda ingresar algún valor útil para tu aplicación, usando el teclado, te es útil la clase `Console` y su método `ReadLine()`. `Console` es una clase que representa a la consola de comandos, al momento de usar el método `ReadLine()` en conjunto con el método `WriteLine()` puedes crear un momento para pedirle al usuario que ingrese la ubicación en tu sistema de archivos donde se encuentra el archivo de texto, almacenarlo en una variable y usarlo posteriormente.

> Según el sitio de [Microsoft MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) acerca del método 
>   `Console.ReadLine()`:
>
> El método ReadLine lee una línea del flujo de entrada estándar. (Para
>   la definición de una línea, consulte el párrafo después de la lista
>   siguiente). Esto significa que si el dispositivo de entrada estándar es el 
>   teclado, el método ReadLine se bloquea hasta que el usuario presiona la 
>   tecla ENTER.

La siguiente modificación a tu código logra lo que necesitas:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;


public struct alumne
{
    public string nom, cognom1, cognom2, població, adreça, dni;
    public int edat;

}

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            alumne[] alumnes = new alumne [5];
            // Creamos la variable que almacenará la ubicación del archivo.
            string DirArchivo = "";

            // Con este ciclo validamos que la entrada del usuario no esté vacía.
            while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DirArchivo))
            {
                // En esta línea imprimimos el mensaje que le avisa al usuario que esperamos algún valor de entrada.
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese a continuación la ubicación del el archivo: \n");
                // Con esta línea tomamos lo introducido por el usuario y se lo asignamos a la variable DirArchivo.
                DirArchivo = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(DirArchivo))
                {
                    string line;

                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error general");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

El método `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` te ayuda a validar si la entrada del usuario es nula o está vacía. En caso de que sea así tomará el valor de `true`. Por lo tanto el bucle `while` se ejecutará mientras que el usuario no ingrese algún texto. Puedes quitarle el bucle `while` y usar lo que está en su interior, tan solo es el bucle una mejora para validar la entrada del usuario.

> Para más información acerca de este tema te dejo las siguiente páginas
>   del sitio MSDN de Microsoft:
>
> [Clase Console.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> [Método Console.ReadLine ().](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> [Método String.IsNullOrEmpty (String).](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> [Clase StreamWriter.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx)